# Getting dataset whose cumulants match user-provided values?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, combinatorics

I'm interested in getting list of numbers whose cumulants match user-specified list of values. Below is an example that works for list of length 2, but I'm interested in generalizing it to higher cumulants. I have a feeling something under Combinatorica set of functionality may help with this, any ideas?

```
genData[cumulants_, n_] := (
   data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
   data = data - Cumulant[data, 1];
   data = data/Sqrt[Cumulant[data, 2]];
   data = data*Sqrt[cumulants[[2]]];
   data = data + cumulants[[1]]; 
   obtainedCumulants = 
    Table[Cumulant[data, i], {i, 1, Length@cumulants}];
   Print["error=", Norm[obtainedCumulants - cumulants]];
   data
   );
genData[{1, 3}, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in determining $k$ observations that produce a specific set of $k$ sample cumulants, then the following should work:

```
(* Set the first 3 cumulants *)
k = {5, 2, 1};

(* Find observations for which the sample cumulants match k *)
n = Length[k];
NSolve[Table[k[[i]] == Cumulant[Table[x[j], {j, n}], i], {i, n}], Table[x[j], {j, n}]]

(* {{x[1] -> 4.6527, x[2] -> 3.46791, x[3] -> 6.87939}, 
    {x[1] -> 6.87939, x[2] -> 3.46791, x[3] -> 4.6527},
    {x[1] -> 3.46791, x[2] -> 4.6527, x[3] -> 6.87939}, 
    {x[1] -> 6.87939, x[2] -> 4.6527, x[3] -> 3.46791},
    {x[1] -> 3.46791, x[2] -> 6.87939, x[3] -> 4.6527},
    {x[1] -> 4.6527, x[2] -> 6.87939, x[3] -> 3.46791}} *)
```

If $k$ is less than the number of desired observations, then you're likely to have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: What if the number of observations is not equal to the number of given cumulants?

Comment: @yarchick Good question.  I await the OP to clarify.  Not only what is needed but "why" it is needed would be helpful.  My limited imagination is not coming up with any practical reason to do so (other than maybe simple textbook examples) but I certainly could be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was indeed looking for solution for general n. The reason is to check how my gradient descent algorithms are affected by higher order moments in the data, so I need to generate some datasets with this properties https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/divergence-convergence.nb

Comment: Another example, NormalDistribution has following cumulants {0,1,0,0,0,...}. It seems I can't produce a sample with similar set of cumulants using recipe above

Comment: There is a difference between sample cumulants and the cumulants of a distribution.  It is certainly possible to obtain a sample from a normal distribution with a variety of values for the sample cumulants.  But only the 2nd cumulant from a normal distribution is non-zero.  That begs the question:  Do you need to sample from distributions with a specified set of cumulants or just have a set of numbers with matching sample cumulants without any consideration of  a distribution?

Comment: To give some context -- I need to check how well my estimation algorithm responds to various settings of higher order cumulants in data. I've been this by taking one of several named distributions in Mathematica, sampling, computing cumulants, and hoping that cumulants are close to what I wanted. Now I'm wondering if there's a more direct method to do this for large n (n=1000000) and a couple of desired cumulants specified (with the rest left unspecified)